# Yii2 Kartik Grid View Export Config

Tags: php, yii2

Summary: Trying to add export in the for csv & pdf download.

Followed [documantation](http://demos.krajee.com/grid) to install. Grid view is otherwise working.

[image]

Also added as module in `config/web.php`'s `$config` array -

```
'modules' => [
        'gridview' =>  [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
            // enter optional module parameters below - only if you need to
            // use your own export download action or custom translation
            // message source
             'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
             'i18n' => [
                 //'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                 //'basePath' => '@kvgrid/messages',
                 //'forceTranslation' => false
             ]
        ]
    ],
```

N.B: I am using basic template and new in yii2. I have tried other fixes like composer update etc as suggested in various posts but really stuck with the problem.

the thing causing problem is - `Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Reset Grid')`

Can somene give me a direction here. I guess it is very simple issue :(

Comment: you don't have `kvgrid` named message category in config. first create it or replace `kvgrid` with `app`.

Comment: Question is how to add it (i.e a new category).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was got above error because of you have not configure `i18n` component in `web.php` file.

You need to configure `i18n` component like as,

```
'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                'kvgrid*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                ],
             ]
         ],
```

Or uncomment the `gridview` modules's `i18n` configuration

```
'gridview' =>  [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
            // enter optional module parameters below - only if you need to
            // use your own export download action or custom translation
            // message source
             'downloadAction' => 'gridview/export/download',
             'i18n' => [
                 'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                 'basePath' => '@kvgrid/messages',
                 'forceTranslation' => true
             ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace

```
Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Reset Grid')
```

to

```
Yii::t('app', 'Reset Grid')
```

in your view file

Answer (score -1):

I suggest better to generate CRUD using the Ajax Crud Generator, it will do all the required task for CRUD and export as well...try this